# To classify finite $p$ group with special property

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I wish to classify following finite $p$ group.

Let $G$ be a finite $p$ group with the property whenever $H$ is a non normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p$, $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ and a normal subgroup $K$ such that all subgroups of $K$ of order $p$ are normal in $G$ and $K$ is isomorphic to the quotient $G/L$ for any normal subgroup $L$ of order $p$.

Comment: Good luck with your project! You haven't asked a question. You will probably get more help if you ask something a bit more specific than "can anyone help me with this?" Do you have any conjectures about this class of groups for example?

Comment: yes it seems to me that G is isomorphic to semidirect product of many C_p (cyclic group of order p)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

Any $p$-group in which there are no non-normal subgroups of order $p$ (such as abelian groups or generalized quaternion groups)  will trivially satisfy your hypotheses.

But apart from that I don't believe that there are any examples. Let $H = \langle h \rangle$ be a non-normal subgroup of order $p$, and $G = K \rtimes H$. Since $K \cong G/L$ for any subgroup $L$ of $K$ of order $p$, and all subgroups of $K$ of order $p$ are normal in $G$, it follows that the image $HL/L$ of $H$ in $G/L$ is normal and hence also central in $G/L$. So $[h,g] \in L$ for all $g \in G$. Now if $K$ had another subgroup $L'$ of order $p$, then we would also have $[h,g] \in L'$ and hence $[h,g]=1$ so $H \le Z(G)$, contrary to assumption. So $K$ has a unique subgroup $L$ of order $p$, and so, by a standard result, $K$ is cyclic or generalized quaternion. But neither of those groups are semidirect products, so we cannot have $G/L \cong K$, contradiction.

Comment: This looks good! The groups with no non-normal subgroups of order $p$ are more varied than just the abelian or generalized quaternion 2-groups. These are the groups of all whose elements of order $p$ are central, and were studied by John Thompson and others under several names. (I studied them as duals to powerful groups until I realized they had been studied quite extensively 50 years earlier.)

Comment: In fact it is not necessary to use the result about $p$-groups with a unique subgroup of order $p$, because it is clear anyway that such groups cannot decompose as a nontrivial semidirect product.